# Integrating WHMCS login with my SaaS applications

Tags: php, authentication, saas, whmcs

I am offering an online cart solutions as a SaaS model. Each customer can register and get an online cart for himself to sell his products.

I have also WHMCS as a billing system for my clients. I want to integrate the login of WHMCS with my SaaS application.

Means, if any customer logs in to the SaaS application, it automatically become logged in to WHMCS, so that when he clicks on the WHMCS member link in his SaaS application, he logs in automatically, and vice verse.

I know there is a login module integration in WHMCS but it must redirect to the WHMCS login page to work!!, which is the thing I don't want. I Want to do the login process myself.

Please advice.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for single sign-on property of WHMCS.
WHMCS supports single sign on, you can do that by youself, or purchase an addon to that.
For more information : http://app.onelogin.com/connector/whmcs-single-sign-on